# Dell inspiron n5010 showing bigger screen and icons and Blurry screen

Tags: drivers, dell-inspiron

I am having problem with my dell laptop (dell inspiron n5010). Last night i install window and now text, icons and other things are showing bigger and Blurry. Even after 10 minutes my eyes are paining. 
I don't know which driver i have to install to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can try to reinstall the latest display card driver. We can download the latest display card driver of Dell inspiron n5010 on dell official website, then reinstall it.

The following is Dell official website, we select the display driver based on our dell laptop:
https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/products/laptop/inspiron_laptop?app=drivers

Hope it helps.

Comment: [This page](https://www.dell.com/support/home/in/en/indhs1/product-support/product/inspiron-15-intel-n5010/drivers) has lot of drivers but i don't know which driver will solve my problem. Please check this page and let me know name of that driver.

Comment: Would you please provide the Service Tag of your laptop. It needs Service Tag to determine which type of display card driver your laptop should install. We can see Service Tag  in the label behind your laptop.